# Convert strings to Java objects automatically

Tags: java, data-binding, data-conversion

I want to convert user input that comes as `Map<String, String[]>` to objects in Java. More specically I want to convert the params of a HttpServletRequest to the fields of an arbitrary domain object.

I'd like to have something like this:

```
Domain d = Converter.convert(params, new Domain());
```

If there is more than one element in the string array, which is the value of a map entry, it should be converted to a list or array. Maybe the locale should be considered for date and currency conversion. And a list of conversion errors would be nice.

Is there a library with such a converter?

Would you call it "converter"? I think it is often called "data binding", but that is the wrong term in my opionion, since it is related to binding model values to GUI elements, what is a slightly different thing - isn't it?

Comment: Any half-decent web framework will do this for you, why are you trying to do it yourself?

Comment: Struts is an example of a framework that does this sort of thing for you. Maybe you can extract what it does.

Comment: Agreed, this should be handled automatically. Can you tell us your environment, b/c maybe there is a simpler way that writing it yourself

Comment: I'm working on a minimalistic web framework ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your web framework does not support this functionality have a look at
http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/ ,espeically the beanutils package which has classes with similar purposes (maybe exactly the same) that you want.

You may also consider switching to a more mature framework ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use this plain code as it is only an example. You should add some pretty exception handling and a loop through a map. But generally the idea is like this:

```
void putValue(String name, String value, Object object) throws Exception {
    String setterName = "set"+name.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()+name.substring(1);
    Method m = object.getClass().getMethod(setterName, String.class);
    if (m!=null) {
        m.invoke(object, value);
    }
}
```

This code, given a parameter name **'name'** will try to find a method `setName(String name)` and call it with the given value.